# OR reading lists

Tags: discussion

[In the future, if the OR.SE proposal progresses to its "public beta" stage,] I'd like to see curated reading lists/must-reads on specific "OR topics" (in the spirit of, e. g., [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), but more focused on particular domains than just "all things OR") being a part of this site's "user experience".

What are your feelings about this -- and, if you think that's a "generally speaking, a neat idea", how to proceed about this: Agree on topics, domain experts/moderators per "thread", set up community wikis, let things play out from there? Make it somehow a part of the OR.SE FAQ? Some completely other approach?

Your thoughts/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think we can not have OR topics. However, if we restrict ourselves to optimization, then we can easily make such a good guide. Otherwise, The Definitive C++ Book Guide would be The Definitive Computer Science Book Guide, which would be impossible :)